# Average formula for Google Sheets with substitution over some figures

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a row of figures from 0 to 2, some cells are empty. I need to count an average for them, but with the rule that would count 2 as 1. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> with the rule that would count 2 as 1

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:1); 
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null"; 0); 2; 1))))
```

[image: 1]

Comment: It's gotta be wrong, cause average couldn't be more than 1. Everything above 1 is considered as 1. Also I'm sorry but copy pasting didn't help. I've changed cell names. What should I do?

Comment: @ДимаР.  **`with the rule that would count 2 as 1`** and **`everything above 1 is considered as 1`** are two different things

Answer (score 0):

> everything above 1 is considered as 1

```
=AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:1=""; ;
                      IF(A1:1<2 ; ROUNDDOWN(A1:1; 0);
                      IF(A1:1>=2; 1; )))))
```

[image: 5]

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps there is a language/communication issue here.

Do you mean:

1. That all of your numbers are between 0 and 2 (with no numbers lower than 0 and no numbers higher than 2)?
2. Do you mean that 0 should count as 0%, 1 should count as 50% and 2 should count as 100% (or, in decimal format, 0 counts as 0, 1 counts as 0.5, and 2 counts as 1)?
3. Is this statistical (e.g., population sample or probability)?

If "YES" to all of these, you may just need a simple formula.

Let's say your numbers are all in A2:J2. You would just need this:

`=AVERAGE(A2:J2)/2`

Comment: Previous comment solved it. I didn't mention that there could be only whole numbers in range from 0 to 2. And all of it is to count successful actions in percents and 2 not really differs from 1 percentagewise, but could mess heavily when counting average.

Comment: @ДимаР. Well, then update your question so that it contains all necessary information